# Alternatives to numpy einsum

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

When I calculate third order moments of an matrix `X` with `N` rows and `n` columns, I usually use `einsum`:

```
M3 = sp.einsum('ij,ik,il->jkl',X,X,X) /N
```

This works usually fine, but now I am working with bigger values, namely `n = 120` and `N = 100000`, and `einsum` returns the following error:

> ValueError: iterator is too large

The alternative of doing 3 nested loops is unfeasable, so I am wondering if there is any kind of alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that calculating this will need to do at least ~n<sup>3</sup> × N = 173 billion operations (not considering symmetry), so it will be slow unless numpy has access to GPU or something. On a modern computer with a ~3 GHz CPU, the whole computation is expected to take about 60 seconds to complete, assuming no SIMD/parallel speed up.

---

For testing, let's start with N = 1000. We will use this to check correctness and performance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy
import time

numpy.random.seed(0)

n = 120
N = 1000
X = numpy.random.random((N, n))

start_time = time.time()

M3 = numpy.einsum('ij,ik,il->jkl', X, X, X)

end_time = time.time()

print('check:', M3[2,4,6], '= 125.401852515?')
print('check:', M3[4,2,6], '= 125.401852515?')
print('check:', M3[6,4,2], '= 125.401852515?')
print('check:', numpy.sum(M3), '= 218028826.631?')
print('total time =', end_time - start_time)
```

This takes about 8 seconds. This is the baseline.

Let's start with the 3 nested loop as the alternative:

```
M3 = numpy.zeros((n, n, n))
for j in range(n):
    for k in range(n):
        for l in range(n):
            M3[j,k,l] = numpy.sum(X[:,j] * X[:,k] * X[:,l])
# ~27 seconds
```

This takes roughly half a minute, no good! One reason is because this is actually four nested loops: `numpy.sum` can also be considered a loop.

We note that the sum can be turned into a dot product to remove this 4th loop:

```
M3 = numpy.zeros((n, n, n))
for j in range(n):
    for k in range(n):
        for l in range(n):
            M3[j,k,l] = X[:,j] * X[:,k] @ X[:,l]
# 14 seconds
```

Much better now but still slow. But we note that the the dot product can be changed into a matrix multiplication to remove one loop:

```
M3 = numpy.zeros((n, n, n))
for j in range(n):
    for k in range(n):
        M3[j,k] = X[:,j] * X[:,k] @ X
# ~0.5 seconds
```

Huh? Now this is even much more efficient than `einsum`! We could also check that the answer should indeed be correct.

Can we go further? Yes! We could eliminate the `k` loop by:

```
M3 = numpy.zeros((n, n, n))
for j in range(n):
    Y = numpy.repeat(X[:,j], n).reshape((N, n))
    M3[j] = (Y * X).T @ X
# ~0.3 seconds
```

We could also use broadcasting (i.e. `a * [b,c] == [a*b, a*c]` for each row of X) to avoid doing the `numpy.repeat` (thanks @Divakar):

```
M3 = numpy.zeros((n, n, n))
for j in range(n):
    Y = X[:,j].reshape((N, 1))
    ## or, equivalently: 
    # Y = X[:, numpy.newaxis, j]
    M3[j] = (Y * X).T @ X
# ~0.16 seconds
```

If we scale this to N = 100000 the program is expected to take 16 seconds, which is within the theoretical limit, so eliminating the `j` may not help too much (but that may make the code really hard to understand). We could accept this as the final solution.

---

Note: If you are using Python 2, `a @ b` is equivalent to `a.dot(b)`.

Comment: Great idea really. If I may add a bit of broadcasting here, we could avoid creating `Y` and directly get the iterative output : `(X[:,None,j]*X).T @ X`. That should give us some further performance boost.

Comment: @Divakar: Thanks! Updated.